# Preencher células com NA por uma sequencia lógica anual no R

Tags: r, matriz, lógica

Eu tenho um dataframe com 25 pessoas e as respectivas idades de 2012 a 2015, mas em alguns anos as idades não foram preenchidas.

```
id<-c(1:25)
idade_2012<-c(21, 18, 19, 25, 20, 12, 12, 13, 14, 29, 40, 11, 15, 14, 24, 16, 14, 12, 13, 14, 12, 21, 14, 16, 13)
idade_2013<-c(22, NA, 20, NA, NA, 13, 13, 14, 15, 30, 41, 12, 16, 15, 25, NA, 15, 13, 14, 15, 13, 22, 15, NA, NA)
idade_2014<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, 15, 16, 31, NA, 13, 17, 16, 26, 18, NA, 14, 15, NA, 14, 23, 16, NA, NA)
idade_2015<-c(NA, NA, NA, 28, NA, 15, 15, 16, 17, NA, NA, 14, NA, 17, 27, 19, NA, 15, 16, NA, NA, 24, 17, NA, 16)

df<-data.frame(id, idade_2012, idade_2013, idade_2014, idade_2015)
df
```

### df[image: df original]

### Eu gostaria de obter como resultado um df todo preenchido com a sequencia lógica de idade, conforme imagem.[image: df preenchido]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não entendi o que você pretende com isso, mas parece que toda a informação que você precisa está em `idade_2012`

Para preencher as outras colunas basta fazer

```
id<-c(1:25)
idade_2012 <- c(21, 18, 19, 25, 20, 12, 12, 13, 14, 29, 40, 11, 15, 14, 24, 16, 14, 12, 13, 14, 12, 21, 14, 16, 13)
idade_2013 <- idade_2012 + 1
idade_2014 <- idade_2012 + 2
idade_2015 <- idade_2012 + 3

df<-data.frame(id, idade_2012, idade_2013, idade_2014, idade_2015)
df
```

Para um caso mais geral você pode obter o ano de nascimento de cada id com a biblioteca `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   gather(idade_ano, idade, -id) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(idade)) %>% 
   separate(idade_ano, c("prefix", "ano"), sep = "_") %>% 
   mutate(ano = as.integer(ano)) %>% 
   mutate(nascimento = ano - idade) %>%
   select(id, nascimento) %>%
   distinct()
```

Você deveria considerar eliminar as colunas idades e ficar apenas com o ano de nascimento, se possível.

Comment: Sim, mas em alguns casos eu não tenho 2012, 2013, 2014, dessa forma com esse script não daria certo.